# Stubbing a class level constant in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My class is structured something like this:

```
class Abc
    ONE_CLASS_LEVEL_CONSTANT_BEING_READ_FROM_DB = GloablAttributeValue.read_from_db 
    def some_method_that_use_above_constant
        # this function behaves differently for different values of ONE_CLASS_LEVEL_CONSTANT_BEING_READ_FROM_DB
    end
end
```

Now i want to unit test some_method_that_use_above_constant on the basis of different values ONE_CLASS_LEVEL_CONSTANT_BEING_READ_FROM_DB .
Is this possible to stub out value of ONE_CLASS_LEVEL_CONSTANT_BEING_READ_FROM_DB, so that i can test it for different values in `rspec` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [this doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant), with the version 2.11 of Rspec this should work:
`stub_const("Abc::ONE_CLASS_LEVEL_CONSTANT_BEING_READ_FROM_DB", 5)`

Comment: thanks, sounds promising let me try it out and i will update once tested.

Comment: this works like magic! thank you. I have marked it as expected answer!